# Iphone USSD connection in background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gsm, ussd

I am trying to setup a USSD service with my iPhone. But i want the uSSD connection to be alive in the background (not have the grey popup box when the USSD is connected). The USSD connection will be incoming as I will not be initiating it and currently it automatically gets opened by the phone, bringing me to the grey menu.

I want to basically not have that menu popup and have my program send some information over the USSD connection programatically to the source of the USSD connection. I know there is no USSD API but how can I basically read the USSD # that is calling me, and then basically send the back data that I want through the uSSD tunnel that program setup.

Like said earlier, I can already automatically receive the uSSD connection. I just need to "run in the background" and then programatically send something back.

Comment: anyone have any idea? still have no ide?

Comment: have you done something about this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing USSD is totally ilegal in iOS,
Recently  i listen about some way to do that by using **CoreTelephony**
you must know that the CoreTelephony is a **private** API and you can not use it for
legal apps
Finally there are no API to do that via iOS until this comment written.

Answer (score 0):

I face similar problem, I find a way to make it legal

send a bug report to apple and ask for supporting USSD
http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/